# CSS grids not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using VS Code for some practice and grids aren't displaying in the dev tools.

Here's an example of what I have so far:

```css
#navBar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 25px 400px 200px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 10px 25px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <img class="logo" src="../assets../images/logo.svg">

  <div id="navLinks">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">New</a>
    <a href="#">Popular</a>
    <a href="#">Trending</a>
    <a href="#">Categories</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome! I see the grid just fine in dev tools. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Fsdfwed — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @disinfor I'm using Firefox Dev Edition to test it, and it can't seem to see the grid. There's no option to view the grid lines like there normally is.

Comment: you defined the sizes for a grid 5 cols x 3 rows on an element that has 2 children. If for example you'll use that same css ruleset for the selector #navLinks you'll see the 5 anchor elements spread on the same row spaced like you defined 50px 25px 400px 200px 50px

Comment: if by seeing the grid you mean how to see the borders of the elements placed according to the grid layout, you can add a rule like `#navBar > *{border: solid;}`

Comment: I misworded my question. I meant FIREFOX dev tools

Comment: I'm also using FF Dev edition and I can see the grid lines and see that you have teh outer `#navBar` set to grid. https://imgur.com/a/FJBGcpi

Answer (score 0):

```css
div#navBar {   
    grid-template-columns: 50px 25px 400px 200px 50px;
    grid-template-rows: 10px 25px 10px;
    display: table-caption;
}
```

You can use display:table-caption